# Is it possible to use Google MAP API to locate nearest universities and schools when the user type his current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am making an android application and I am thinking instead of having a database and input numerous universities and schools in our area, is it possible to use google map instead? For the user to just type the location and identify the nearest college and universities base on the location the user typed by the use of google map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any search features built into the Android SDK, but you can certainly still use the [Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

The following example is a search request for places of type 'university' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?type=university&location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You simply need to specify the `type` as `university` or `school`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) for other supported types.

Comment: Great, I think I can still come up with the same result I want with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the google place api as follows
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?type=university&location="current lattitude","current longitude"&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY
for more info visit https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search.